# Picture is changed to previously uploaded image when "Change picture"-Dialog is closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture, uploader

In my profile I have two pictures for my profile, one from Gravatar and one that I uploaded previously. As profile picture I have selected my Gravatar.

Now I have the problem, that my Profile image changes to the uploaded image, when I select "Change picture" -> "Upload a new picture" and then close "Add Image"-PopUp without uploading any image.

I have reproduced this on two different PCs and different browsers. I can even reproduce this on my tablet.

Can anybody confirm this behavior. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a caching problem.

Comment: I can confirm this on your account. It appears to be a bug wherein clicking "Upload a new picture" assumes automatically that you're going to set your custom picture instead of Gravatar, so if you cancel it just closes out entirely and assumes the same as if you just picked "Uploaded picture".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.